# Why can't i set my Footer component to be 100% width of the page in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass, layout, next.js13

Guys im just stuck with painful issue where i'm trying to set my `Footer` component to be in 100% width of the page because of it's overridden by its layoutContainer class at which i declared some grid layout rules as you can also figure from the classes below,but the thing is, yeah, i can remove that class from there and just keep going with a new set of scss rules but then my grid layout will just not appear so it wont make any sense for me, as i want that my all other components(Header, HeroSection, Filter etc.) to stay in grid area`(grid-column: span 12)` dealing with `.layoutContainer` class where its rules are declared in globals.css...

I think its all will be clear if you take a closer look at the pic below, any help is highly appreciated since im all stuck trying to deal with the issue for a day, **here what i want it to be:**
[image]

## **`globals.css`**

```
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   
  }
  
  html, body {
    font-family: 'Inter Tight', sans-serif;
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  
    height:auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: radial-gradient(28.55% 28.55% at 50.00% -0.00%, #2D2849 0%, #2A2542 100%);

    
  }
  
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
  }
  
  
.layoutContainer {
        
  max-width: 1728px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 165px;
  padding-right: 165px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(6,auto);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  background: radial-gradient(28.55% 28.55% at 50.00% -0.00%, #2D2849 0%, #2A2542 100%);
}
```

## `page.tsx`

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
   <> 
    <StoryCarousel stories={storyData} />
      <HeroSection/>
      <Filter icon = {RocketIcon} showFilter= {true} title = "Test Filtresi" productCount={50}/>
    <CardContainer/>


    
   </> 
  )
}
```

## `layout.tsx`

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (

    <html lang="en">
      
      <body>
          
        <div className='layoutContainer'>
          <Header/>
        {children}
        <Footer/>

        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

## **`Footer.module.scss (for my Footer component only)`**

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    background: url('./footer.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 427px;
    
    
   

}
```

footer should span the full width of the page without being affected by layoutContainer class.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at your layout Container:

```css
.layoutContainer {
        
  max-width: 1728px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 165px;
  padding-right: 165px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(6,auto);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  background: radial-gradient(28.55% 28.55% at 50.00% -0.00%, #2D2849 0%, #2A2542 100%);
}
```

you are using a padding on left and right site (`padding-left: 165px;` and `padding-right: 165px;`)  inside your `div` with the class `.layoutContainer`

you have unlimited options to fix it..
one of the ways you can do it is to set the footer outside of the container

```html
<div className='layoutContainer'>
   <Header/>
   {children}
 </div>
 <Footer/>
```

and also take care with your width attribute in css, your are using `max-width` which is different to `width`

Comment: yeah thanks for help but this just didnt work out, as i want the main home layout to span right in the center of the page, so i gave it a bit padding both from left and right, nothings gonna change even if i make it margin, too.  e.g (margin-left:15px, margin-right:165px).